# lanelet2 map and pcd map didn't match in map frame

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Description:
I create a pcd file by lidar slam, and create a lanelet2 hd map by Autoware online map tool(i double checked my  MGRS cooridinate, and i do followed the instruction in lanelet2 provider located in AutowareAuto in map edit part),  Then i can run simulation planning and mpc control only rely lanelet2 map and simulation node,  seems the map is working and everything working fine now . Then i want to geo-align pcd map and lanelet2 map in rviz just like AVP demo, then i picked a cooridinate(WGS84) in some online map (i double checked the coordinate about latitude/longitude/altitude ), then provide  this cooridinate  'param yaml ' for lanelet2 provider and Map publisher node, THEN i launch rviz2,  BUT !! THE lanelet2 Marker is not located in MAP origin LIKE AVP DEMO, AND the PCD(viz_ndt_map which published by map publisher) located in map origin.

THE Lanelet2 Marker is 90000m(y), -3000(x)m  FAR AWAY from pointcloud map(located in map's frame origin) , anybody can give some clue ?

************** Solution ***************

The lanelet2 is base on an Rough approximation MGRS coordinate, what you should do:

1: transform your MGRS (you uesed to create lanelet2 map) to wgs84 (mgrs_latitude, mgrs_longitude)

2: get real WGS84 coordinate for your map origin (wgs84_latitude,  wgs84_longitude)

3: calcuated offset value: offset_latitude = mgrs_latitude - wgs84_latitude, offset_longitude = mgrs_longitude - wgs84_longitude;

4: fill param file for lanelet2_map_provider

pcd map and lanelet2 map are in same coordinate in map frame !

Node: the reason about this is  when we createing lanlet2 map, we use Rough approximation MGRS coordinate, but it not real coordinate, since it already wiried in  xxx.osm file, we can't modified it, then when we use an real wgs84 coordinate as it's UTM origin, there will generate a huge gap between lanelet2 map and it origin(wgs84 coorinate), but when you add an offset , we change the wgs84 origin to it's  creating origin( BUT IT'S STILL NOT TRUE ORIGIN),  there is no gap between this two cooridinate.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/392193/lanelet2-map-and-pcd-map-didn%27t-match-in-map-frame/) by [utopia_david](https://answers.ros.org/users/89362/utopia_david/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2021-12-03

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2021-12-04**:
Please copy/paste your solution into the answer field, and click the checkmark if you want to.

**Comment by [utopia_david](https://answers.ros.org/users/89362/utopia_david/) on 2022-01-30**:
OK~~~~~~~~~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

The answer you provided in the post unfortunately did not work for me.
However I found a simpler way to resolve this issue.

You simply need to get MGRS of your location for example for
lat, lon: 50.86095, 11.71346
the MGRS is: 32U PB 90956 37870

Then you put the MGRS square: 32U PB in the map in Vector Map Builder
and set in the map config file lat, lon of the origin of that MGRS
in this example that would be: 50.54338, 10.41134

And set the offset for lat, lon in lanelet2_map_provider.param.yaml to 0.0

Hope it is helpfull for anyone having thiss isue in the future

---

Originally posted by [TopRamen](https://answers.ros.org/users/92960/topramen/) with karma: 36 on 2022-01-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2